# Draw a Line in Photoshop and it becomes an immovable object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I'm looking for an answer to the most obvious thing in the world.

1. I create a new layer on a blank canvas
2. I draw a line with the line tool
3. I switch to the move tool and try to move the line
4. the line will not move.  It seems I can't even select it.

I've even tried free transform to move it.  I can't resize it, I can't move it, I can't select it.  Totally weird.

How do I draw a simple horizontal line and then move it around???

Comment: The only type of "line" you can't move with the move tool in any circumstance is a path. If the tool mode (the dropdown on the left side in the tool options bar) says `Path` when you draw it, then you can't use the move tool. What I don't get is... paths can be free transformed (resized, etc...). As well as moved with the path selection tool, but that I feel is irrelevant. I think you need to maybe give us like a video of you making it and trying to move it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you draw a **shape**...

[image]

**Shapes** create both a Shape *Layer* and a path... either can be moved.

[image]

Or a **path**....

[image]

Paths only create a new path in the **Paths Panel** and can only be moved using the **Selection** or **Direct Selection** tools.

[image]

or **pixels**....

[image]

Pixels can only be drawn on a *existing* layer and do *not* crete anything in the Path Panel.

[image]

All three can be moved, but *how* they are moved may be different. If it's a path you need the Selection/Direct Selection tools. For Shapes or Pixels you can use the move tool on the *layer* associated with the line.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshops *Move Tool* (<kbd>V</kbd>) works in layers, so in order to *move* the line, you would have to move the **layer** (that the line is on). With the *Move Tool* you can actually click anywhere, since it's the layer and not a particular path/object.

It's possible that you selected a different layer. Make sure to select the **Shape** layer with the line.

Here's a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTTPT.gif) showing that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

By default, these days, creating a line with the line tool will create a "Live shape", not a Path. Live shapes can be tweaked indefinitely, having properties such as stroke width, color, fill (lines can be expanded into boxes), etc. I don't have a definitive answer for your question because I struggle with Photoshop's move tool as well, as it requires you to click exactly on the object in order to move it. It used to be different. Perhaps there's a shortcut or another way of doing this. Here are just a few images to illustrate what I said:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select your shape, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, then click to drag.